# Representation of references in Java

Tags: java, generics, reference

Anjelika Langer in her Generics FAQ writes the following regarding the decision for Java to go with *code reuse* instead of *code specialization* for generic types :

> Code specialization is particularly wasteful in cases where the
>   elements in a collection are references (or pointers), **because all
>   references (or pointers) are of the same size and internally have the
>   same representation**. There is no need for generation of mostly
>   identical code for a list of references to integers and a list of
>   references to strings.  Both lists could internally be represented by
>   a list of references to any type of object. The compiler just has to
>   add a couple of casts whenever these references are passed in and out
>   of the generic type or method. Since in Java most types are reference
>   types, it deems natural that Java chooses code sharing as its
>   technique for translation of generic types and methods.

So first question is it true that all references are of the same size and internally share the same representation?

If the answer is true that what properties does all the references in Java share?

Comment: Ask SO whether an expert in the field is correct. Interesting logic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> So first question is it true that all references are of the same size and internally share the same representation?

Yes.  (Why would you *imagine* that someone as knowledgeable as Anjelika Langer would get that wrong???)

> If the answer is true that what properties does all the references in Java share?

They all have a type that has `Object` as its ultimate supertype.  Hence they all provide all methods in the [`java.lang.Object`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html) API.